# Assigning an html file to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to assign an html file to a variable ?
for example, I want to assign a file called helloworld.html which has **Hello World**  inside it to var html and I will use that variable later on.
I'm using nodemailer to create a simple e-mail template. (Node.js)
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to store mail message into html file ?

Comment: Googling `node.js read file into variable` seems to have good results. I'm closing this as a duplicate of the first hit there; if it somehow doesn't fit your needs or I'm misunderstanding this, ping me in a comment.

Comment: Alright thank you, I knew there's an answer out there in SO but couldn't find it.